# Low priority request in PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

I Have a site and a database with 5 million rows, it's working like a charm. However, I'm running a cleanup cronjob each hour, to put the old data to a 'log' table and delete the old data, and in this time the server response is very slow. Is it possible to give that job a lower priority via PHP or MySQL?

Comment: What type of database is it? MyIsam, InnoDB, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the heaviest task in your cleanup is the DELETE operation for which you can use LOW_PRIORITY.

DELETE syntax from MySql [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html):

> DELETE **[LOW_PRIORITY]** [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name ...

and the description:

> If you specify **LOW_PRIORITY**, the server delays execution of the DELETE until no other clients are reading from the table. This affects only storage engines that use only table-level locking (such as MyISAM, MEMORY, and MERGE).

Answer (score 2):

There is such a thing in MYSQL as low-priority-updates - its documented here -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_low-priority-updates

** only works for MyISAM, MEMORY, MERGE storage engines ....

Answer (score 1):

One of the low priority requests in MYSQL is [INSERT DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html). But it only works on INSERT, not UPDATE or DELETE.

EDIT: I just knew that DELETE also can be delayed!

Comment: This is one of my query:$sql = "INSERT INTO #__bet_oddslog (id, team1, team2, league, sport, time, q1, q2)";

     $sql .= " SELECT a.id, a.team1, a.team2, a.league, a.sport, a.time, AVG(b.q1) as q1, ";

     $sql .= " AVG(b.q2) as q2 FROM #__bet_details as a, #__bet_1x2_best as b WHERE time<'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("now"))."' AND a.id=b.bet_id GROUP BY b.bet_id"; There is a selection as well, does it work in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe `INSET DELAYED` doesn't work for `INSERT ... SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to do the copying of old data on a slaved replication server. That way, the heavy load is entirely on that slave box. Once the copying is finished on slave, you could delete on master.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html), you could add `LOW_PRIORITY` to your query. So, your query would become:

```
$sql = "INSERT LOW_PRIORITY INTO #__bet_oddslog (id, team1, team2, league, sport, time, q1, q2)"; $sql .= " SELECT a.id, a.team1, a.team2, a.league, a.sport, a.time, AVG(b.q1) as q1, "; $sql .= " AVG(b.q2) as q2 FROM #__bet_details as a, #__bet_1x2_best as b WHERE time<'".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("now"))."' AND a.id=b.bet_id GROUP BY b.bet_id";
```